# Azure Cli keep giving docker deamon running not supported error

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I been trying to deploy docker with azure private registry, i been following below tutorial and when i tried **az acr login -n**  command azure shell keeps giving me  **This command requires running the docker daemon, which is not supported in Azure Cloud Shell**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-azure-cli

how could i enable docker daemon in azure cli

Comment: What do you want to achieve by logging in to the ACR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the Azure Cloud Shell, you could install Docker locally because the Azure Cloud Shell doesn't include all required Docker components (the docker daemon), you can't use the Cloud Shell for [this quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-azure-cli). Docker provides packages that easily configure Docker on any [macOS](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/), [Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/), or [Linux](https://docs.docker.com/install/) system.

Then you also need to [install Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) locally.

Comment: Actually without connecting through cli when ssh from my local machine problem is disappeared anyway thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, then I tried to login from Shell console locally from VM and it was successful.

Steps:

1. Docker login `<loginServer>`
2. Visit locally your `<ResourcesGroup>` from Azure Manager and find passwords, where you'll see current login and password
3. Finish your login with login and password data

To push image to Registry use CLI